# img2pdf how to give file range

Tags: bash, image-processing

I am using **img2pdf** inside a bash script. The script counts number of jpg files ,numbered in ascending order, inside a directory and converts to pdf using img2pdf

```
numjpg=$(ls -l *.jpg | wc -l)

img2pdf --output my.pdf {1..$numjpg}.jpg
```

but the above code produces following error

> img2pdf: error: argument infile: "{1..39}.jpg" does not exist

What is correct way to give file range here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you not just do:

```
img2pdf --output my.pdf $(ls *.jpg|sort -n)
```

Comment: the pdf created would have images jumbled and not in the order i want

Comment: Add `-n` to the sort.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following code to convert image files into a pdf

```
import glob
import re
import img2pdf

dirname = 'C:/images/'
output  = 'C:/image/output.pdf'

# Get all the filenames
filenames = [f for f in glob.iglob(f'{dirname}*.jfif')]
# Sort filenames numerically
filenames = sorted(filenames, key=lambda x:float(re.findall("(\d+)",x)[0]))

with open(output,"wb") as f:
    f.write(img2pdf.convert(filenames))
print(f'Finished converting {output}')
```